# C++ public method inherited from base class can not access private member variable in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, private

I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Animal() : age(1) {}
    void toString(){
        cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
    }
};
class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat() : age(5) {}
    /*
    void toString(){
        cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
    }*/
private:
    int age;
};

int main(){
    Cat tom;
    tom.toString();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run the program, the age of the **tom** variable is 1, not 5. Does the **toString** can not read the **age** variable? If we open the /* */ the toString method in the Cat class, the age will be 5 !

(My english is not good very much. Thanks)

Comment: try `Cat tom = new Cat()`, it seems like what is happening is that the base constructor is being called since you are not explicitly calling the constructor on Cat tom....

Comment: @MatthewPigram: This is C++ not Java. You don't use `new` like that (or at all if you are doing it properly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Cat` is writing to the `age` variable in `Cat`, while `toString()` reads the `age` variable in `Animal`, which, with `Animal`'s constructor, is initialized to `1`.

To solve this, you can provide another constructor for `Animal` which accepts an `age` parameter which is used to initialize `Animal`'s `age` member variable.

```
class Animal{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Animal() : age(1) {}
    Animal(int param_age) : age(param_age) {} // Initialize member variable age with parameter
    void toString(){
        cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat() : Animal(5) {} // Call Animal's constructor that set's the age
};
```

**UPDATE:** Another solution is to add a setter method in `Animal` class that sets its age. You can then call it in `Cat`'s constructor to set the proper age.

```
class Animal{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Animal() : age(1) {}
    void setAge(int age) { this->age = age; }
    void toString(){
        cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
    }
};
class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat() {
        setAge(5);
    }
};
```

Yet another alternative is to make `Animal`'s `age` member `protected`

```
class Animal{
protected:  // THIS
    int age;
public:
    Animal() : age(1) {}
    void toString(){
        cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
    }
};
```

And remove `Cat`'s `age` variable in the class definition. Despite its simplicity, this approach gives you more risk in encountering the ["brittle base class" problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class). Thus, I recommend the former solution as it is less prone to the said problem, and IMHO better sticks to the *"write against interfaces, not implementations"* principle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `Cat::age` in the `Cat` constructor, not the `Animal::age` used by `Animal::toString`.

Change the visibility of `Animal::age` to protected.

```
class Animal {
protected:
    int age;
public:
    Animal() : age(1) {}
    void toString(){
        cout << "Age: " << age << endl;
    }
};
```

Don't redeclare a second `age` (which becomes `Cat::age`). Instead, change the value of `age` (`Animal::age`).

```
class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    Cat() {
        age = 5;
    }
};
```

Comment: That's horrible. Protected is a bad decision for this case. Protected should be avoided when possible as it opens up the class to abuse.

Comment: I have no idea what the case *is*, so I can't make that call. There are *several* things I would do differently, but this directly answers the OP. But point taken. Personally, I would pass the age into `Animal::Animal`, but with default values. That's me speculating about code whose purpose I can only guess.

Comment: OK. Protected is bad in nearly all situations; avoid like the plague.

Comment: *"nearly all situations*"? @LokiAstari, that is a ideological bias specific to yourself and other people who always choose unnecessarily complicated constructs and cram every best practice they think they know into a holy crusade of code explosion. It's that kind of blanket (or almost blanket) statement that breeds programmers with strong opinions and horrible code. Start simple, and then design *from there*. You may have noticed the OP doesn't have .h and .cpp files. Maybe he doesn't want them. I'm not sure, but that's a discussion for another day, with more context than is present here.

Comment: Here you opening up implementation details of the base class to derived types. Thus tightly coupling the base class and implementation detail in the derived type(s). This is just so you can set age in the constructor (basically using a sledge hammer to crack open a nut and exposing much more than you need to). The simpler solution that maintains correct encapsulation would be to modify the animal constructor to accept an age parameter (seems much simpler). Unfortunately you "Start simple" concept is not simple and eventually leads to much harder to solve maintenance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
private:
    int age;
public:
    Animal(int a = 1)   // Pass in the age as a parameter.
       : age(a)         // Default to 1.
    {}

    // Prefer generic print function rather than toString()
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Animal const& a) {
        return s << "Age: " << a.age << '\n';  // Prefer '\n' rather than endl
                                               // Unless you really want to flush
                                               // the stream (this is not usually
                                               // the case).
    }
};
class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat()
       : Animal(5)      // Now you can call the base class constructor
    {}                  // And get it to set 5
private:
    // int age;         // don't have a private copy here.
                        // use the one that is available in the base class.


    // Prefer generic print function rather than toString()
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Cat const& a)
    {
        // Print Cat
        // Then use the Animal priting function to print more information about the object.
        return s << "A Cat: " << static_cast<Animal const&>(*a);
    }
};

int main(){
    Cat tom;

    // tom.toString(); // Don't use a toString() method.
                       // overload operator<< to print to a stream.
                       // If you want to convert to a string the just print
                       // to a string stream.

    std::cout << tom;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```